# Script to modify .xcconfig file generated by Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcconfig

**How can I modify the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` field in the .xcconfig generated at pod install step?**

End goal: Only weakly link certain Pods, so they can be loaded with `dlopen` at runtime.

---

I noticed in the `Pod-Target.debug.xcconfig` generated at pod install, it has this: `OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "AFNetworking"`, if I change that to `-weak_framework`, it does what I want to do.

[This](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6494) Cocoapods issue talks about doing it through a post_install hook, however `config.build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS']` doesn't write to that file.

---

PS: I know that the use of `dlopen` is not recommended, however I'm working with conflicting hardware libraries where I cannot have two loaded at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code to your `Podfile` and run `pod install` again

```
post_install do |installer|
    workDir = Dir.pwd
    xcconfigFilename = "#{workDir}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Target/Pod-Target.debug.xcconfig"
    xcconfig = File.read(xcconfigFilename)
    newXcconfig = xcconfig.gsub(/-framework "AFNetworking"/, "-weak_framework \"AFNetworking\"")
    File.open(xcconfigFilename, "w") { |file| file << newXcconfig }
end
```

Comment: works perfectly for me! as at the end of "bundle exec pod install" a specific "xcconfig" was generated, we can just alter it a little bit

Answer (score -1):

A little modification of answer by VoidLess which I think might be useful:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
            xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
            xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/-framework "YourFramework"/, "-weak_framework \"YourFramework\"")
            File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
        end
    end
end
```