# Edit Cocoapods xcconfig file arm64

Tags: ios, cocoapods, arm64, podspec

I noticed that Pods-target.debug file generated by the pod install has "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator] = arm64".
I want to remove this line from the PODS config file.

I know as per the below script we can edit
[Script to modify .xcconfig file generated by Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241896/script-to-modify-xcconfig-file-generated-by-cocoapods)

But is there any other way to modify this?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply reinstall the Pods.

To remove the line "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator] = arm64" from the PODS config file, you can modify the .xcconfig file generated by CocoaPods. Here's how you can do it:

Open your Xcode project.
In the Project Navigator, locate the Pods project (usually at the bottom).
Expand the Pods project and find the .xcconfig file that corresponds to your target configuration (e.g., Pods-YourProjectName.debug.xcconfig for the debug configuration).
Open the .xcconfig file in a text editor.
Locate the line "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator] = arm64" and remove it.
Save the file.
By removing this line, you will allow the arm64 architecture to be included in the build for the iOS Simulator.

Please note that modifying the .xcconfig file directly may not be recommended in some cases. It's always a good practice to understand the implications of such changes and ensure that they align with your project requirements.

Also, please consider this:
`sudo gem install cocoapods`
`pod deintegrate`
`pod clean`